# $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$ for all $x,y \in\mathbb{R}$. If $g$ is continuous at $0$, prove that $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-equations

$g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$ for all $x,y \in\mathbb{R}$.

If $g$ is continuous at $0$, prove that $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you know about continuity?  Have you thought about this at all?

Comment: If you have a look at [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation/), you will find there several facts about this functional equations, that have already been asked and answered on this website.

Answer (score 1):

For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
g(x)=g(x+0)=g(x)g(0),
$$
so that $g(x)(1-g(0))=0$.  So, either $g(x)=0$ for all $x$, in which case $g$ is certainly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, or $g(0)=1$.

Suppose $g(0)=1$. Fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and let $\epsilon>0$ be given.  Note that for any $\delta>0$, we have
$$
g(x+\delta)=g(x)g(\delta)\qquad\text{and}\qquad g(x-\delta)=g(x)g(-\delta).
$$
But, we can make $g(\pm\delta)$ close to 1 by choosing $\delta$ small, by continuity of $g$ at 0.  Do you see how to use this idea to finish the problem?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
g(0) & = 1 \\
\lim_{h \to 0} g(x + h) & = \lim_{h\to 0} g(x)g(h) = g(x)g(0) = g(x)
\end{align}